# Jquery datatable rails with html5 export buttons not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, datatables, jquery-datatables-rails

I added this gem

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: "rweng/jquery-datatables-rails", branch: "master"
```

and then updated my application.js and application.css
with

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

Now in my products.js.coffee file

```
table = jQuery ->
    $("#products").DataTable()

new jQuery.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
})

table.buttons().container()
  .appendTo( $('#exportButtons', table.table().container() ) )
```

and I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: c is undefined
```

I'm stuck and don't have any idea where is the problem.
Is this datatable gem does not support the latest release of datatables export buttons

Comment: Have you considered trying the gem from [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) instead? I always prefer to get UI related libraries from there as they do not rely on other maintainers to keep up with the library updates.

Comment: I prefer not using any gem now, and just files from datatables as it is.Everything is working fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to explicitly download and include JS & CSS files for button.

`application.js` looks as follows-

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require ./DataTables/buttons/dataTables.buttons.min
//= require ./DataTables/buttons/buttons.bootstrap.min
//= require ./DataTables/buttons/buttons.html5.min
```

`application.scss` looks as below-

```
*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
*= require ./DataTableStyles/buttons/buttons.dataTables.min
*= require ./DataTableStyles/buttons/buttons.bootstrap.min
```

I have downloaded `buttons` extension for tables explicitly and added to the asset pipeline in folder `DataTables` & `DatableStyles`.

Also don't forget to include `html5` version of buttons-

```
buttons: [
    'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5'
]
```